# Commit data in DataGridView in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to read the values of a DataGridViewRow in the CellEndEdit event but I notice that they have not been stored yet, so if I read a cell the value is still empty and the row is still in the editing state. The DataGridView is associated with a DataTable, it does not have a Binding.
I tried all these lines of code but none worked. How can I commit the data and exit the modification?

```
vGrid.BindingContext[vGrid.DataSource].EndCurrentEdit();
vGrid.CurrentRow.DataGridView.EndEdit();
vGrid.EndEdit();
vGrid.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
```

-------------------------------EDIT-------------------------
What I am trying to do is read the value of a cell after it has been entered, but I am still in edit mode. To do that I thought about committing, but as I said, it doesn't work. To add a row I use the datatable linked with Datatable.NewRow() I hope I was clear.

Comment: I am not understating what you are trying to do. In my test, if I wire up grids `CellEndEdit` event and read the value in the cell, then the new value is there and also in the underlying data source. How are you trying to “read” the cells value?

Comment: When the DataGridView is bound to a datasource that supports notifications, as a DataTable, the `CellParsing` and `CellEndEdit` events can be used to parse (validate) and accept or refuse the edit (`[DataGridView].CancelEdit()`), so you of course can read the current value. This if *The DataGridView is associated with a DataTable* means that the `[DataGridView].DataSource = [Your DataTable]`, not if you have added Rows *manually*. -- You should clarify what you're actually trying to do (not how you're trying to do it).

Comment: @JhonG I use vGrid.CurrentRow.Cells["code"].Value.ToString()

Comment: Sorry for the delay, however I never got your flag because you spelled my name wrong. However, now you have me confused. You state that… _”What I am trying to do is read the value of a cell after it has been entered, but I am still in edit mode.”_ … ? … The grid’s `CellEndEdit` event will fire when the cell is “leaving” edit mode. So, if you want to get the value “before” the user ends the edit mode, then you will probably need to use some other event(s). Can you supply a reproducible example of what you are trying to do and what is not working?

Comment: Example, the user types a single character into a cell. This sets that cell into “edit mode.” Once in edit mode, what are you trying to “commit” BEFORE the user leaves the edit mode? As noted, in my test, even while in edit mode, unlike your claim… the new values are present in the cell. It is possible to wire up a key pressed event for the cell to capture each character typed into a cell but it is unclear if this is the issue.

Comment: In other words, without a clear example of what is not working as expected, it will be difficult to proffer a solution. Your current problem is not reproducible. In my tests, the values ARE being committed, but you state they are not. Can you show an example of where the vales are not committed?

Comment: I look for them more clearly: in the CellEndEdit event I expect that the value has already been written in the cell, instead, using debug, I see that the value has not been written and the row is still in edit mode. For now I'm using CellValueChanged, which reads the value but always before the Commit. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

While that's not what I wanted I solved by using the CellValueChanged event, which reads the cell value even without committing.